# git gitlab laravel not all files are added

Tags: git, laravel, gitlab

This is a complete newbie question. I have just started using git and would really appreciate some help here. Below are the steps I followed

1. Created a project in gitlab.com
2. cloned it on local machine using "git clone"
3. created a laravel project within the created directory using composer
4. made changes.
5. added all files using "git add --all"
6. used "git commit --all"
7. added commit message and saved
8. used "git push --all"

When I download the zipped file it only shows 66 files 29 folders, whereas the original folder has 3000+ files and 600+ folders. Should it not push the whole project at first commit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the files in your project root, you will discover a `.gitignore` file. This file defines files, directory and patterns (with wildcards `*`) that should be excluded from GIT.

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/vendor
composer.phar
composer.lock
.env.*.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

The largest directory that doesn't get committed is `/vendor`. And that's for a reason. These files are **dependencies**. The framework itself and other libraries, packages your application depend on. Those files get downloaded by composer when you install Laravel or run `composer update`. They don't need to be included in your repository because you shouldn't touch them and therefore have no reason to track changes.

They should be downloaded (and updated from time to time) on every machine your working.

**What you pushed** is your *actual application*. Models, controllers, views etc

Comment: Thanks for the help. So when I work in another PC how should I proceed? If I clone the project that wouldn't work would it?

Comment: Clone it and run `composer update` afterwards (obviously you need to have composer available)